# Input function for scipy calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I need help with this code:

```
import numpy
import math
from scipy.optimize import fmin_slsqp

def f(x, sign=-1.0):   
    tmp = exec('(' + str(input()) + ')')
    return tmp

res = fmin_slsqp(f, [5, 5], iter = 10000)
print(res)
```

I'm trying to minimize function from user input. Example of function: `20*x[0]**0.3*x[1]**0.4 - 2*x[0] - 3*x[1]`. But something goes wrong and i get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'`
I have spent a lot of time to make it work, but cant solve this problem. What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) returns `None`. Use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) does. Use `eval`.

And [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string; You don't need to convert it to string:

```
def f(x, sign=-1.0):
    return eval('(' + input() + ')')
```

Comment: Well, eval works, thanks a lot! But then i have another error: `failed in converting 8th argument g of _slsqp.slsqp to C/Fortran array`. It seems like error of scipy module and it has no solution. Nothing changes from different views of functions. So scipy is not useful?

Comment: There are chances `(' + input() + ')` will not return a scalar (required by slsqp. Try with `return eval(input())`